# Dynamically generate new named class from string with coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I have looked around and have found a number of questions which approach [using-a-string-to-define-the-class-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366127/instantiate-a-javascript-object-using-a-string-to-define-the-class-name) and  [dynamic-class-generation-in-coffeescript>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523719/dynamic-class-generation-in-coffeescript) but neither of them exactly address my problem, so I am wondering whether I making some fundamental mistake in my approach to the problem.

In the loop below I am looping through some data parsed from JSON. For each set of data I want to extend my `class Robot` with `string = new Robot` where `string` is a string.

Currently my code does not produce any errors, and successfully creates new `Robots` but since their name is a string, trying to access them with `robot1.move()` or `robot2.doSomeOtherClassyThing()` does not work and tells me they are undefined.

This seems like it should not require a verbose helper function to make it work. What am I missing here?

```
 createRobots: -> # process robot commands
        createXcoord = missionData.xCoord
        createYcoord = missionData.yCoord
        createOrient = missionData.orientation
        createInstru = missionData.robotInstructions
        for command in createOrient
          robot = 'robot' + (_i + 1)
          name = robot
          robot = new Robot \ # create named Robot 
            name
          , createXcoord[_i] 
          , createYcoord[_i] 
          , createOrient[_i] 
          , createInstru[_i]
          console.log(robot)
```

I think what is happening is that the variable `"robot = 'string'` is written over when the `robot = new Robot` is declared.

The outcome I am hoping for is `string1 = new Robot`, `"string2 = new Robot"`. Does that make sense? jsfiddle.net/7EN5y/1

Answer (score 2):

You need to add them to a context.  If you want them to be global, create a variable like this:

```
# Either the browser root, or the CommonJS (e.g. Node) module root
root = window or exports
```

If you want an object that holds robots, add such an object to the root.

```
root.robots = []
```

Then when creating robots, add them to such an object.

```
robot = 'robot' + (_i + 1)
name = robot
robot = new Robot # ...
root[name] = robot # or robots[name] = robot
```

You may then use code like `robot1.move()`, or `robots.robot1.move()` (depending on if you attached them to the root or not).

Comment: But then you'd need to know the names elsewhere in order to access them as `root[name]`. I think something along the lines of `root.robots = { }` is the only sane way to proceed.

Comment: Sorry I marked your answer as accepted and then not. It helps in so much as it fixes a scope issue I had, but does not actually seem to address the question I asked.

Comment: I think what is happening is that the variable `"robot = 'string'` is written over when the `new Robot` is declared. The outcome I am hoping for is `string = new Robot`. Does that make sense? http://jsfiddle.net/7EN5y/1/

Comment: I guess I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish.  What is the purpose of the line `should = 'shouldnt'`?

Comment: @happilyUnStuck, this is my [best attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/7EN5y/2/) at understanding what you want.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand thank you for trying. What I am trying to achieve is to create a new class name from a string. `shouldwork = new Class` works if I want a class instance called `thisdoesnotwork` but I only have that value as a string "thisdoesnotwork"` and I assign it to variable `shouldwork = "thisdoesnotwork"` and then declare the class as `shouldwork = new Class` i get a class named `shouldwork` and not `thisdoesnotwork`. I know my naming was unclear, it was 4am over here! =)

Comment: so what I am asking is whether it is possible in javascript to acheive  something that approximates `"string" = new class` `string.works()`

Comment: `something = new Class` is equivalent to `window.something = new Class` and `window["something"] = new Class`.  So if you have a variable called `MyVar` which holds the string `"something"`, do `window[MyVar] = new Class`.